# Use more than 1 shader on display

Tags: c#, opengl, shader

This question is based on the Giawa tutorials on OpenGL. I have completed tut6 & tut9 separately, but now I want to combine the two. I.e. I want that cube spinning while a bunch of stars is floating around. However, I'm pretty new two OpenGL but it looks like they use different types of shaders. So I wrote two shaders, but now when I try to run it my cube is transparent and the stars does not display. Is it possible to display both on screen at the same time correctly? Below is my code.

```
using System;
using Tao.FreeGlut;
using OpenGL;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace OpenGLTutorial6
{
    class Program
    {
        private static int width = 1280, height = 720;
        private static ShaderProgram program, program_2;
        private static VBO<Vector3> cube, top_pyramid, bottom_pyramid, cubeNormals, bottom_pyramidNormals, top_pyramidNormals, star;
        private static VBO<Vector2> cubeUV, top_pyramidUV, bottom_pyramidUV, starUV;
        private static VBO<int> cubeQuads, top_pyramidTrianlges, bottom_pyramidTrianlges, starQuads;
        private static bool fullscreen = false;
        private static bool left, right, up, down;
        private static List<Star> stars = new List<Star>();
        private static Random generator = new Random(Environment.TickCount);
        private static float theta = (float)Math.PI / 2, phi = (float)Math.PI / 2;

        private static Texture crateTexture, 
            brickTexture,
            cracked_glassTexture,
            desert_surfaceTexture,
            numbersTexture,
            ziggyTexture,
            starTexture;

        private static System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch watch;
        private static float angle;
        private static int rotate = 1;
        private static bool lighting = true;

        private class Star
        {
            public float angle;
            public float dist;
            public Vector3 color;

            public Star(float Angle, float Distance, Vector3 Color)
            {
                this.angle = Angle;
                this.dist = Distance;
                this.color = Color;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // create an OpenGL window
            Glut.glutInit();
            Glut.glutInitDisplayMode(Glut.GLUT_DOUBLE | Glut.GLUT_DEPTH);
            Glut.glutInitWindowSize(width, height);
            Glut.glutCreateWindow("SCREENSAVER");

            // provide the Glut callbacks that are necessary for running this tutorial
            Glut.glutIdleFunc(OnRenderFrame);
            //Glut.glutIdleFunc(OnRenderFrame_2);
            Glut.glutDisplayFunc(OnDisplay);
            //<<<<<<<<<<<<< KEYBOARD FUNCTIONS
            Glut.glutSpecialFunc(new Glut.SpecialCallback(OnKeyPress));
            Glut.glutKeyboardFunc(OnKeyboardDown);
            Glut.glutKeyboardUpFunc(OnKeyboardUp);
            //<<<<<<<<<<<<< DISPOSE
            Glut.glutCloseFunc(OnClose);

            // enable depth testing to ensure correct z-ordering of our fragments
            Gl.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);
            Gl.Disable(EnableCap.DepthTest);
            Gl.Enable(EnableCap.Blend);
            Gl.BlendFunc(BlendingFactorSrc.SrcAlpha, BlendingFactorDest.One);

            //<<<<<<<<<<<   COMPILE SHADER PROGRAMS
            program = new ShaderProgram(VertexShader, FragmentShader);
            program_2 = new ShaderProgram(VertexShader_2, FragmentShader_2);

            //set the view and projection matrix, which are static throughout this tutorial
            program.Use();
            program["projection_matrix"].SetValue(Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(0.45f, (float)width / height, 0.1f, 1000f));
            program["view_matrix"].SetValue(Matrix4.LookAt(new Vector3(0, 0, 10), Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Up));
            program["light_direction"].SetValue(new Vector3(1, 1, 1));
            program["enable_lighting"].SetValue(lighting);


            program_2.Use();
            program_2["projection_matrix"].SetValue(Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(0.45f, (float)width / height, 0.1f, 1000f));
            program_2["view_matrix"].SetValue(Matrix4.LookAt(new Vector3(0, 0, 20), Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Up));

            //<<<<<<<<<     LOAD TEXTURES
            crateTexture = new Texture("crate.jpg");
            brickTexture = new Texture("bricks.jpg");
            cracked_glassTexture = new Texture("crack.jpg");
            desert_surfaceTexture = new Texture("desert.jpg");
            numbersTexture = new Texture("numbers.jpg");
            ziggyTexture = new Texture("ziggy.jpg");
            starTexture = new Texture("star.bmp");

            // each star is simply a quad
            star = new VBO<Vector3>(new Vector3[] { new Vector3(-1, -1, 0), new Vector3(1, -1, 0), new Vector3(1, 1, 0), new Vector3(-1, 1, 0) });
            starUV = new VBO<Vector2>(new Vector2[] { new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(1, 0), new Vector2(1, 1), new Vector2(0, 1) });
            starQuads = new VBO<int>(new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 }, BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer);

            // create 50 stars for this tutorial
            int numStars = 50;
            for (int i = 0; i < numStars; i++)
            {
                stars.Add(new Star(0, (float)i / numStars * 4f, new Vector3(generator.NextDouble(), generator.NextDouble(), generator.NextDouble())));
            }


            // create a crate with vertices and UV coordinates
            cube = new VBO<Vector3>(new Vector3[]
            {
                new Vector3(-1.5, 0, -0.5), new Vector3(-0.5, 1, -0.5), new Vector3(-0.5, 1, 0.5), new Vector3(-1.5, 0, 0.5),
                new Vector3(-0.5, 1, -0.5), new Vector3(0.5, 1, -0.5), new Vector3(0.5, 1, 0.5), new Vector3(-0.5, 1, 0.5),
                new Vector3(0.5, 1, -0.5), new Vector3(1.5, 0, -0.5), new Vector3(1.5, 0, 0.5), new Vector3(0.5, 1, 0.5),
                new Vector3(1.5, 0, -0.5), new Vector3(1.5, 0, 0.5), new Vector3(0.5, -1, 0.5), new Vector3(0.5, -1, -0.5),
                new Vector3(0.5, -1, 0.5), new Vector3(0.5, -1, -0.5), new Vector3(-0.5, -1, -0.5), new Vector3(-0.5, -1, 0.5),
                new Vector3(-0.5, -1, -0.5), new Vector3(-0.5, -1, 0.5), new Vector3(-1.5, 0, 0.5), new Vector3(-1.5, 0, -0.5)
             });
            cubeUV = new VBO<Vector2>(new Vector2[] {
                new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(1, 0), new Vector2(1, 1), new Vector2(0, 1),
                new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(1, 0), new Vector2(1, 1), new Vector2(0, 1),
                new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(1, 0), new Vector2(1, 1), new Vector2(0, 1),
                new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(1, 0), new Vector2(1, 1), new Vector2(0, 1),
                new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(1, 0), new Vector2(1, 1), new Vector2(0, 1),
                new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(1, 0), new Vector2(1, 1), new Vector2(0, 1) });

            top_pyramid = new VBO<Vector3>(new Vector3[] 
            {
                new Vector3(-1.5, 0, -0.5), new Vector3(-0.5, 1, -0.5), new Vector3(0, 0, -1.5),
                new Vector3(-0.5, 1, -0.5), new Vector3(0.5, 1, -0.5), new Vector3(0, 0, -1.5),
                new Vector3(0.5, 1, -0.5), new Vector3(1.5, 0, -0.5), new Vector3(0, 0, -1.5),
                new Vector3(1.5, 0, -0.5), new Vector3(0.5, -1, -0.5), new Vector3(0, 0, -1.5),
                new Vector3(0.5, -1, -0.5), new Vector3(-0.5, -1, -0.5), new Vector3(0, 0, -1.5),
                new Vector3(-0.5, -1, -0.5), new Vector3(-1.5, 0, -0.5), new Vector3(0, 0, -1.5)
            });
            top_pyramidUV = new VBO<Vector2>(new Vector2[] {
                new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(1, 0), new Vector2(1, 1),
                new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(1, 0), new Vector2(1, 1),
                new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(1, 0), new Vector2(1, 1),
                new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(1, 0), new Vector2(1, 1),
                new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(1, 0), new Vector2(1, 1),
                new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(1, 0), new Vector2(1, 1)});

            bottom_pyramid = new VBO<Vector3>(new Vector3[]
            {
                new Vector3(-1.5, 0, 0.5), new Vector3(-0.5, 1, 0.5), new Vector3(0, 0, 1.5),
                new Vector3(-0.5, 1, 0.5), new Vector3(0.5, 1, 0.5), new Vector3(0, 0, 1.5),
                new Vector3(0.5, 1, 0.5), new Vector3(1.5, 0, 0.5), new Vector3(0, 0, 1.5),
                new Vector3(1.5, 0, 0.5), new Vector3(0.5, -1, 0.5), new Vector3(0, 0, 1.5),
                new Vector3(0.5, -1, 0.5), new Vector3(-0.5, -1, 0.5), new Vector3(0, 0, 1.5),
                new Vector3(-0.5, -1, 0.5), new Vector3(-1.5, 0, 0.5), new Vector3(0, 0, 1.5)
            });

            bottom_pyramidUV = new VBO<Vector2>(new Vector2[] {
                new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(1, 0), new Vector2(1, 1),
                new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(1, 0), new Vector2(1, 1),
                new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(1, 0), new Vector2(1, 1),
                new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(1, 0), new Vector2(1, 1),
                new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(1, 0), new Vector2(1, 1),
                new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(1, 0), new Vector2(1, 1)});

            cubeNormals = new VBO<Vector3>(new Vector3[] {
                new Vector3(0, 1, 0), new Vector3(0, 1, 0), new Vector3(0, 1, 0), new Vector3(0, 1, 0), 
                new Vector3(0, -1, 0), new Vector3(0, -1, 0), new Vector3(0, -1, 0), new Vector3(0, -1, 0), 
                new Vector3(0, 0, 1), new Vector3(0, 0, 1), new Vector3(0, 0, 1), new Vector3(0, 0, 1), 
                new Vector3(0, 0, -1), new Vector3(0, 0, -1), new Vector3(0, 0, -1), new Vector3(0, 0, -1), 
                new Vector3(-1, 0, 0), new Vector3(-1, 0, 0), new Vector3(-1, 0, 0), new Vector3(-1, 0, 0), 
                new Vector3(1, 0, 0), new Vector3(1, 0, 0), new Vector3(1, 0, 0), new Vector3(1, 0, 0) 
            });
            top_pyramidNormals = new VBO<Vector3>(new Vector3[]{
                new Vector3(0,1,0), new Vector3(0,1,0), new Vector3(0,1,0), new Vector3(0,1,0),
                new Vector3(0, -1, 0), new Vector3(0, -1, 0), new Vector3(0, -1, 0),
                new Vector3(0, 0, 1), new Vector3(0, 0, 1), new Vector3(0, 0, 1),
                new Vector3(0, 0, -1), new Vector3(0, 0, -1), new Vector3(0, 0, -1),
                new Vector3(-1, 0, 0), new Vector3(-1, 0, 0), new Vector3(-1, 0, 0),
                new Vector3(1, 0, 0), new Vector3(1, 0, 0), new Vector3(1, 0, 0)
            });
            bottom_pyramidNormals = new VBO<Vector3>(new Vector3[]{
                new Vector3(0,1,0), new Vector3(0,1,0), new Vector3(0,1,0), new Vector3(0,1,0),
                new Vector3(0, -1, 0), new Vector3(0, -1, 0), new Vector3(0, -1, 0),
                new Vector3(0, 0, 1), new Vector3(0, 0, 1), new Vector3(0, 0, 1),
                new Vector3(0, 0, -1), new Vector3(0, 0, -1), new Vector3(0, 0, -1),
                new Vector3(-1, 0, 0), new Vector3(-1, 0, 0), new Vector3(-1, 0, 0),
                new Vector3(1, 0, 0), new Vector3(1, 0, 0), new Vector3(1, 0, 0)
            });


            cubeQuads = new VBO<int>(new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 
                4, 5, 6, 7, 
                8, 9, 10, 11, 
                12, 13, 14, 15, 
                16, 17, 18, 19, 
                20, 21, 22, 23 }, BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer);

            top_pyramidTrianlges = new VBO<int>(new int[] { 
                0,1,2, 
                3,4,5,
                6,7,8,
                9,10,11,
                12,13,14, 
                15,16,17}, BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer);

            bottom_pyramidTrianlges = new VBO<int>(new int[] { 
                0,1,2, 
                3,4,5,
                6,7,8,
                9,10,11,
                12,13,14, 
                15,16,17}, BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer);

            watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

            Gl.BindTexture(desert_surfaceTexture);
            Glut.glutMainLoop();
        }

        private static void OnClose()
        {
            // dispose of all of the resources that were created
            //must still update
            cube.Dispose();
            cubeUV.Dispose();
            top_pyramid.Dispose();
            top_pyramidTrianlges.Dispose();
            cubeQuads.Dispose();
            crateTexture.Dispose();
            program.DisposeChildren = true;
            program.Dispose();
        }

        private static void OnDisplay()
        {

        }

        private static void OnRenderFrame()
        {
            // calculate how much time has elapsed since the last frame
            watch.Stop();
            float deltaTime = (float)watch.ElapsedTicks / System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.Frequency;
            watch.Restart();

            // use the deltaTime to adjust the angle of the cube
            angle += deltaTime;

            // set up the OpenGL viewport and clear both the color and depth bits
            Gl.Viewport(0, 0, width, height);
            Gl.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

            // use our shader program and bind the crate texture
            Gl.UseProgram(program);

            //<<<<<<<<<<<<   TOP PYRAMID
            // set the transformation of the top_pyramid
            program["model_matrix"].SetValue(Matrix4.CreateRotationY(angle * rotate));
            program["enable_lighting"].SetValue(lighting);
            // bind the vertex positions, UV coordinates and element array
            Gl.BindBufferToShaderAttribute(top_pyramid, program, "vertexPosition");
            Gl.BindBufferToShaderAttribute(top_pyramidNormals, program, "vertexNormal");
            Gl.BindBufferToShaderAttribute(top_pyramidUV, program, "vertexUV");
            Gl.BindBuffer(top_pyramidTrianlges);
            // draw the textured top_pyramid
            Gl.DrawElements(BeginMode.Triangles, top_pyramidTrianlges.Count, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, IntPtr.Zero);


            //<<<<<<<<<<    CUBE
            // set the transformation of the cube
            program["model_matrix"].SetValue(Matrix4.CreateRotationY(angle *rotate));
            program["enable_lighting"].SetValue(lighting);
            // bind the vertex positions, UV coordinates and element array
            Gl.BindBufferToShaderAttribute(cube, program, "vertexPosition");
            Gl.BindBufferToShaderAttribute(cubeNormals, program, "vertexNormal");
            Gl.BindBufferToShaderAttribute(cubeUV, program, "vertexUV");
            Gl.BindBuffer(cubeQuads);
           // draw the textured cube
           Gl.DrawElements(BeginMode.Quads, cubeQuads.Count, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, IntPtr.Zero);

           //<<<<<<<<<<<<   BOTTOM PYRAMID
           // set the transformation of the bottom_pyramid
           program["model_matrix"].SetValue(Matrix4.CreateRotationY(angle * rotate));
           program["enable_lighting"].SetValue(lighting);
           // bind the vertex positions, UV coordinates and element array
           Gl.BindBufferToShaderAttribute(bottom_pyramid, program, "vertexPosition");
           Gl.BindBufferToShaderAttribute(bottom_pyramidNormals, program, "vertexNormal");
           Gl.BindBufferToShaderAttribute(bottom_pyramidUV, program, "vertexUV");
           Gl.BindBuffer(bottom_pyramidTrianlges);
           // draw the textured bottom_pyramid
           Gl.DrawElements(BeginMode.Triangles, bottom_pyramidTrianlges.Count, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, IntPtr.Zero);

            Glut.glutSwapBuffers();
        }

        private static void OnRenderFrame_2()
        {
            watch.Stop();
            float deltaTime = (float)watch.ElapsedTicks / System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.Frequency;
            watch.Restart();

            // perform rotation of the scene depending on keyboard input
            if (right) phi += deltaTime;
            if (left) phi -= deltaTime;
            if (up) theta += deltaTime;
            if (down) theta -= deltaTime;
            if (theta < 0) theta += (float)Math.PI * 2;


            // set up the OpenGL viewport and clear both the color and depth bits
            Gl.Viewport(0, 0, width, height);
            Gl.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

            //<<<<<<<<<      STARS
            // make sure the shader program and texture are being used
            Gl.UseProgram(program_2);
            Gl.BindTexture(starTexture);
            // calculate the camera position using some fancy polar co-ordinates
            Vector3 position = 20 * new Vector3(Math.Cos(phi) * Math.Sin(theta), Math.Cos(theta), Math.Sin(phi) * Math.Sin(theta));
            Vector3 upVector = ((theta % (Math.PI * 2)) > Math.PI) ? Vector3.Up : Vector3.Down;
            program_2["view_matrix"].SetValue(Matrix4.LookAt(position, Vector3.Zero, upVector));

            // loop through the stars, drawing each one
            for (int i = 0; i < stars.Count; i++)
            {
                // set the position and color of this star
                program_2["model_matrix"].SetValue(Matrix4.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(stars[i].dist, 0, 0)) * Matrix4.CreateRotationZ(stars[i].angle));
                program_2["color"].SetValue(stars[i].color);

                Gl.BindBufferToShaderAttribute(star, program_2, "vertexPosition");
                Gl.BindBufferToShaderAttribute(starUV, program_2, "vertexUV");
                Gl.BindBuffer(starQuads);

                Gl.DrawElements(BeginMode.Quads, starQuads.Count, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, IntPtr.Zero);

                // update the position of the star
                stars[i].angle += (float)i / stars.Count * deltaTime * 2;
                stars[i].dist -= 0.2f * deltaTime;

                // if we've reached the center then move this star outwards and give it a new color
                if (stars[i].dist < 0f)
                {
                    stars[i].dist += 5f;
                    stars[i].color = new Vector3(generator.NextDouble(), generator.NextDouble(), generator.NextDouble());
                }
            }

            Glut.glutSwapBuffers();
        }
        public static void OnKeyPress(int theKey, int x, int y)
        {
            switch (theKey)
            {
                //<<<<<<<   ROTATE
                case Glut.GLUT_KEY_F5:
                    {
                        rotate += 1;
                        Console.WriteLine("Hallo!");
                    }
                    break;
                case Glut.GLUT_KEY_F6:
                    {
                        rotate -= 1;
                    }
                    break;

                //<<<<<<<<<<    TEXTURES
                case Glut.GLUT_KEY_F7:
                    {
                        Gl.BindTexture(cracked_glassTexture);
                    }
                    break;
                case Glut.GLUT_KEY_F8:
                    {
                        Gl.BindTexture(desert_surfaceTexture);
                    }
                    break;
                case Glut.GLUT_KEY_F9:
                    {
                        Gl.BindTexture(brickTexture);
                    }
                    break;
                case Glut.GLUT_KEY_F10:
                    {
                        Gl.BindTexture(ziggyTexture);
                    }
                    break;
                case Glut.GLUT_KEY_F11:
                    {
                        Gl.BindTexture(numbersTexture);
                    }
                    break;
            }
            Glut.glutPostRedisplay();
        }


        private static void OnKeyboardDown(byte key, int x, int y)
        {
            if (key == 'w') up = true;
            else if (key == 's') down = true;
            else if (key == 'd') right = true;
            else if (key == 'a') left = true;
            else if (key == 27) Glut.glutLeaveMainLoop();
        }

        private static void OnKeyboardUp(byte key, int x, int y)
        {
            if (key == 'w') up = false;
            else if (key == 's') down = false;
            else if (key == 'd') right = false;
            else if (key == 'a') left = false;
            else if (key == 'f')
            {
                fullscreen = !fullscreen;
                if (fullscreen) Glut.glutFullScreen();
                else
                {
                    Glut.glutPositionWindow(0, 0);
                    Glut.glutReshapeWindow(1280, 720);
                }
            }
        }
        public static string VertexShader = @"
#version 130

in vec3 vertexPosition;
in vec3 vertexNormal;
in vec2 vertexUV;

out vec3 normal;
out vec2 uv;

uniform mat4 projection_matrix;
uniform mat4 view_matrix;
uniform mat4 model_matrix;

void main(void)
{
    normal = normalize((model_matrix * vec4(floor(vertexNormal), 0)).xyz);
    uv = vertexUV;

    gl_Position = projection_matrix * view_matrix * model_matrix * vec4(vertexPosition, 1);
}
";

        public static string FragmentShader = @"
#version 130

uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform vec3 light_direction;
uniform bool enable_lighting;

in vec3 normal;
in vec2 uv;

out vec4 fragment;

void main(void)
{
    float diffuse = max(dot(normal, light_direction), 0);
    float ambient = 0.2;
    float lighting = (enable_lighting ? max(diffuse, ambient) : 1);

    fragment = lighting * texture2D(texture, uv);
}
";

        public static string VertexShader_2 = @"
#version 130

in vec3 vertexPosition;
in vec2 vertexUV;

out vec2 uv;

uniform mat4 projection_matrix;
uniform mat4 view_matrix;
uniform mat4 model_matrix;

void main(void)
{
    uv = vertexUV;

    gl_Position = projection_matrix * (view_matrix * model_matrix * vec4(0, 0, 0, 1) + vec4(vertexPosition.x, vertexPosition.y, vertexPosition.z, 0));
    //gl_Position = projection_matrix * view_matrix * model_matrix * vec4(vertexPosition, 1);
}
";

        public static string FragmentShader_2 = @"
#version 130

uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform vec3 color;

in vec2 uv;

out vec4 fragment;

void main(void)
{
    fragment = vec4(color * texture2D(texture, uv).xyz, 1);
}
";
    }
}
```

Also I've added some other textures that is not in the original tutorials

Comment: Seriously? You've pasted a wall of code and you expect us to read it all? Just change the technique when you want to render some object in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

From scanning through your code, it looks like you have most of what you need. To render both items at the same time, you basically have to add the rendering code that you currently have in `OnRenderFrame_2()` to `OnRenderFrame()`. Make sure that you only have one `glClear()` at the start, and one `glutSwapBuffers()` at the end.

If the outline of your code currently looks like this:

```
OnRenderFrame
    prepare rendering of Item 1
    glViewport
    glClear
    glUseProgram(program1)
    render Item 1
    glutSwapBuffers

OnRenderFrame_2
    prepare rendering of Item 2
    glViewport
    glClear
    glUseProgram(program2)
    render Item 2
    glutSwapBuffers
```

Rearrange it like this:

```
OnRenderFrame
    prepare rendering of Item 1
    prepare rendering of Item 2
    glViewport
    glClear
    glUseProgram(program1)
    render Item 1
    glUseProgram(program2)
    render Item 2
    glutSwapBuffers
```